# where does this margin is come from?

Tags: html, css, margin

On the below code an unwanted margin is automatically created from an unknown source.please help me to figure it out "where does that is come from?". i"m adding the snippet and and screen shot on below for better understanding of the problem

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCl9E.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCl9E.png)

```css
#main-body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: yellow;
}

#title-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: red;
}

#button-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#data-container{
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.btn{
    width:25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*margin:auto;*/
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-body">
            <div id="title-container"></div>
            <div id="button-container">
                <div id="home-button" class="btn"> Home</div>
                <div id="update-button" class="btn"> Update</div>
                <div id="delete-button" class="btn"> Create New</div>
                <div id="logout-button" class="btn"> Log Out</div>
            </div>
            <div id="data-container"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's from the `display: inline-block`, use `float: left` instead

```css
#main-body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: yellow;
}

#title-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: red;
}

#button-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#data-container{
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.btn{
    width:25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*margin:auto;*/
    float :left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-body">
            <div id="title-container"></div>
            <div id="button-container">
                <div id="home-button" class="btn"> Home</div>
                <div id="update-button" class="btn"> Update</div>
                <div id="delete-button" class="btn"> Create New</div>
                <div id="logout-button" class="btn"> Log Out</div>
            </div>
            <div id="data-container"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks bro for your help